# Using pyplot to plot with a ln y scale and a ln(ln(x)) scale

Tags: matplotlib

I'm want to plot with a ln(y) axis and a ln(ln(x)) axis.

Up to now I have been using `pyplot.yscale('log',basey=numpy.e)` and `pyplot.xscale('log',basex=numpy.e)` to plot on ln scales, however I haven't found a method to extend this to ln ln scales.

How could this be done?